# h2 database config NOT read by springBoot IOC

Tags: spring-boot, properties, h2, hikaricp

I am working on some POC for which I am using h2 database with following details in application.properties file:

```
#datasource
ds.pc.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
ds.pc.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
ds.pc.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
ds.pc.hikari.pool-name=pc-hikari-dbcp
ds.pc.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
ds.pc.driver-type=thin
ds.pc.validation-query=Select 1 from dual
ds.pc.primary=true
ds.pc.username=sa
ds.pc.password=

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

I have defined my beans as below:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig
{
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConversionServiceFactoryBean conversionServiceFactoryBean()
    {
        return new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    }
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "pcJdbcTemplate")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate pCJdbcTemplate()
    {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(pCDataSource());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ds.pc")
    public DataSource pCDataSource()
    {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

It fails with below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:958) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

But when I hard code the data source properties as below then it works:

```
    @Primary
    @Bean 
    public DataSource pCDataSource() 
    {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("sa"); hikariConfig.setPassword("");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(
                "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig); 
    }
```

Tried with changing properties as below:

```
ds.pc.jdbc-url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
ds.pc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Still it doesn't work.

What's wrong in my application.properties file that it's not being read?

Also I am not able to see h2 console at localhost:8080/h2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my application.properties file was under a folder named *appConfig* under src/main/resources.

**Solution 1:** Rename *appConfig* to *config* .

Go to the section 2.3. Application Property Files at [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html). It explains why config folder works.

**Solution 2:** move properties files directly under src/main/resources

Silly me. Had spent quite few hours to just find things can be simple.